# background animation don't work with overflow: hidden

Tags: css, animation, scroll, overflow

I'm stuck I'm trying to display this background animation over all my containers/entire page but ever since i implented scroll snap they don't want to coexist I know the overflow hidden is the problem is their anyway you guys think I bypass this. i want the background animation to display over the entire screen while still having the snap scroll...i tried everything from javascript to switching around postions... I also want the animation to be behind the text if possibly
link:
https://jsfiddle.net/bossmanricky/3q2h0pnb/2/

```
       html
   <h1>please help</h1>
```

Comment: The text could easily be positioned on top of the animation with `position: relative; z-index: 5` and you could set a lower z-index to the `.lines` . Not sure I understand correctly what you trying to achieve with the animation though. What do you mean "to display over the entire screen" Isn't it working like this at the moment?

Comment: wow...i never heard of z-index i researched it and it looks like that's what i need....and by "to display over the entire screen" i mean i want the background animation to be continuously running while I'm scrolling but I cant scroll with overflow: hidden active and with overflow: hidden remove the animation isn't static  and doesnt stick when scrolling but thanks for the tip....ill keep you updated